# Get the variable outside foreach function? using jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my `foreach()` function, Now its working fine, But how can i get the variable email outside the `foreach()

```
$(".bulkclass").each(function(){
    if($(this). prop("checked") == true){
        ischecked = 1 ;
        userkey  = $(this).val();  
        var email = $(this).attr("data");
        alert(email);
    }
});
```

I need like this

```
$("#mailToo").attr("href", "mailto:" + email);
```

Comment: declare email before each loop and fill in loop, then after you can access it out side of each.

Comment: `var email = '';` before `$(...).each(function()`

Comment: surely I will try this

Comment: i followed your steps But i am getting null in return.

Comment: Where you are writing this line:- `$("#mailToo").attr("href", "mailto:" + email);`? inside `each()`? or outside somewhere else?

Comment: outside each function

Comment: you need to put it inside `.each()` function because multiple mail id's can come through `.each()` function. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: You are wrong bro

Comment: And why? if you came with single mail-id then why to use `.each()` ? what's the purpose?

Comment: I have multiple mail id, not a single mail id

Comment: Now i have a answer bro, thanks for your time

Comment: @SivaGanesh  if you got the answer then either delete your question or put an  answer of your own question with proper description and code.

Comment: Yeah all ready post my answer bro, Just check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks mate now i have a solution @Devsi Odedra @Erwin

```
  var newEmails = '';
           $(".bulkclass").each(function(){
               if($(this). prop("checked") == true){
                  ischecked = 1 ;
                   userkey  = $(this).val();  
                    if(newEmails == ''){
                       newEmails += $(this).attr("data");
                    }else{
                        newEmails += ','+ $(this).attr("data");
                    }
               }

            });
$("#mailToo").attr("href", "mailto:"+ newEmails);
```

Comment: Instead of conditionally adding comma, push everything onto an array and then use `.join(",")`.

Comment: Sure bro, I will follow it